# Nslog print certain numbers

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am trying to only print number divisible by 10 when I push a button any suggestions please? And I can change the for loop so don't ask about that.

```
-(IBAction)begin:(id)sender{
for (int k=0;k<=20;k++){


   NSLog( @"%d",k);


   }
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(k % 10 == 0) { NSLog( @"%d", k); }
```

That is the modulus operator. You are essentially asking "if k divided by 10 has zero remainder, print it"... :)

Comment: This one works great, thanks. I had something like this but it was printing remainders lol.

Comment: No worries. Don't forget to accept the answer if it is what you are looking for! :)

Comment: I didn't fortget, stack overflow make me wait 10 minutes before accepting.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(IBAction)begin:(id)sender{
for (int k=0;k<=20;k++){

if(k %10 == 0){
   NSLog( @"%d",k);


   }
     }
```